# I'm generating a profile page for every /profile/url. How can I only generate a page for accounts on my website?

Tags: python-3.x

The title is a bit unwieldy, so I'll try to explain. The code below is currently behaving like this: It's generating a page for literally EVERY url past /profile/ . So if I type in for example, `http://localhost:8080//profile/foo`, I'm taken to an empty profile page.

I only want to create profile pages for users that exist on my site. So I'd like my site to behave like this:

`http://localhost:8080//profile/foo` = page not found

`http://localhost:8080//profile/existinguser` = existing user's page

it current behaves like this:

`http://localhost:8080//profile/foo` = foo's page

`http://localhost:8080//profile/existinguser` = existing user's page

This doesn't seem like it should be hard to do, but I'm at a loss as to how I should handle this. If anyone can point me in the right direction It'd be appreciated. Thank you.

```
users = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users")
# Dynamically generate and populate profile pages for each user
# TODO Currently exists problem, there is a profile page for literally url. Needs to check against users
@app.route("/profile/<username>")
def profile(username):
user=username
elo = db.execute("SELECT elo from users WHERE username = :username", username=user)[0]["elo"]
return render_template('profile.html', users=users, user=user, elo=elo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it. Code works just as intended with
`query = db.execute("SELECT elo, wins, losses, draws, username from users WHERE username = :username", username=user)
    # If the user does not exist, return apology
    if not query:
        return apology("user does not exist", 404)`